# How setup VM IP via Deploy OVF template?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have OVA image RH8.
How can I setup VM IP address via "Deploy OVF template" ?
I don't see there any option in GUI.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the [OVF deployment documentation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-17BEDA21-43F6-41F4-8FB2-E01D275FE9B4.html):

> Some of the pages in the Deploy OVF Template wizard only appear if the OVF template that you deploy requires additional customization, contains deployment options or has one or multiple vService dependencies.

Further down the documentation you'll see an optional `Customize template page` mentioned, which is missing in your case.

The reason for that is that ovf/ova is a general format that can be used for different hypervisors. Customizations like network configuration or hostname however are implemented differently at different hypervisors.

That means, when you deploy an ovf image that has been created specifically for VMware you will find these options, but if it is a general image you will not find them.

Instead, this configuration is often prompted in the console when the VM is started the first time.